# Commenting multiple lines in an ipython cell

Tags: comments, ipython

Is there a way to comment multiple lines of code in an ipython cell in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use triple-quoted strings. Although this prints a repeats out statement, which I would like to avoid.

```
'''
This is a multiline
comment.
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

To comment multiple lines you can use:

`ctrl` + `/`

This won't print a repeat out statement the way the triple quotes does.

```
""" This is a multi line 
    comment.
"""

Out[1]:' This is a multi line \n    comment.\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>#</kbd> shortcut.

This is a `readline` binding, so it will work on any shell which has GNU `readline` available, like Bash.

To use it simply type the code in an ipython block like:

```py
In [1]: if True:
   ...:     pass
```

Then to comment the complete block, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>#</kbd> anywhere within the cell.
The code will then change to:

```py
In [1]: #if True:
   ...: #    pass
   ...: #
```

To uncomment, we need to pass a numerical argument to this readline function.
It can be done by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>some_number</kbd> anywhere within the cell.

Note that most of the terminals have keybindings for changing tabs mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>- 1 through 9. So if you have a tab opened, try to use a number that won't be allotted to a tab. Like, if you have 5 tabs opened, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> (Any number works. It just needs to be passed to readline instead of being intercepted by the terminal)

Answer (score 0):

For me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>^/~</kbd>. The other solutions didn't work for me.
I'm using windows 10 and Jupyter Notebook.